# Easiest way to fail-fast on an empty attribute using EL?

Tags: java, web-applications, attributes, jstl, el

Is it possible to force an exception to happen when an EL call returns nothing?

I like the convenient ${...} notation that EL provides but I'd like every single call to *pageContext.findAttribute(...)* (that's what EL basically does IIRC) to throw an exception should there be no attribute (or an attribute containing an empty string).

Can I keep using EL or should I use something else?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create your own [`ELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html). You can probably extend [`ScopedAttributeELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ScopedAttributeELResolver.html) and override [`getValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ScopedAttributeELResolver.html#getValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
    Object value = super.getValue(context, base, property);
    if (context.isPropertyResolved() && (value == null)) {
        throw new PropertyNotFoundException("Scoped attribute not found");
    }
    return value;
}
```

In order to register the resolver, create a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do something like the following in [`contextInitialized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29):

```
JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(sce).addELResolver(resolver);
```